# Word 'Eselsbrücke'

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, etymology

As far as I understand this means some kind of trick that helps you to memorise something without deep understanding.
Is it so?
Is there a story behind this word?

Comment: Apparently there is no agreement on the origin. Some possibilities are here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pons_asinorum#Etymology_and_related_terms

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: The (English) _pons asinorum_ has almost nothing to do with the German _Eselsbrücke_ (in the sense of a mnemonic trick). I'd go so far as to call it a false friend.

Comment: @Ingmar, this is one explanation that has been given for the origin, I did not claim that the current meaning is the same.

Comment: Some remarks can be found at [Merkspruch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkspruch#Begriffsherkunft_.E2.80.9EEselsbr.C3.BCcke.E2.80.9C)

Comment: @Ingmar Looks like the German *Eselsbrücke* didn't have the current meaning some 150 years ago: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GE09690#XGE09690

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right about its meaning. An *Eselsbrücke* is, for instance, a word or phrase that helps you to remember something. A good English translation is *mnemonic*.

An example:

```
    OSI-Modell:  
    Alle          Priester       Saufen    Tequila     Nach      Der         Predigt.
    Application / Presentation / Session / Transport / Network / Data Link / Phyiscal
```

About its origin, there's a quite possible version given at [redensarten.net](http://www.redensarten.net/Eselsbruecke.html).

The thing is that a horse (similar to a donkey in many respects) would simply jump over a ditch, a brook or whatever. The donkey, however, won't even go through the ditch.
But if you build a bridge (or take an existing one), the donkey walks over that one without hesitation. <sup>1</sup>

The 'donkey bridge' helps to get to the other side.

In a [television show of ZDF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VslhSTJ1FIQ), they second this story.

---

<sup>1</sup> They mention (and the link in Matthias' comment seconds this) that the original meaning was quite a bit different and that it changed.
However, I am not sure if there's an error in that article or if it's just a little too late for me right now, but I don't quite get it.